# Why is self nil? How would I do this?

Tags: lua

```
t = {}
a = function() print(self) end
t.a = a
t:a()
```

I don't want to pass in self, I want to use the syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function foo:bar() ... end` silently inserts a parameter called `self` as the first argument, making it equivalent to `function foo.bar(self) ... end`. It's not like Javascript where there's a magical `this` variable that's just there.

Your second line should be:

```
a = function(self) print(self) end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
t = {}
function t:a() print(self) end
```

Comment: ty. but I can't define the function on `t`, because the function is defined before `t`